# What does S[1..n] mean for strings and arrays?

Tags: arrays, string, alphabet

I've chanced upon quite a few reference books using definitions stating "for the string S[1..n]" and "in the array A[0..n-1]", and I did look up several sites in related fields but am unable to figure out what this notation means. I know that this question is probably trivial to many and may have been answered prior to this question in a related post, but some help will be deeply appreciated as I'm pretty much stuck..

Comment: The string S, which has characters numbered 1 to n. An array A, with positions numbered 0 to n-1.

Comment: If you view a string as a sequence of characters, then `S[1..n]` means a string from its character at the first index to its nth index. Same goes for the array, 0th element to n - 1 element.

Comment: Ah does that mean that for a string S='abcdef', we have a=1,b=2,...,f=6 in that sense?

Comment: In that case, what does it mean when we have an alphabet = [1..n]? From my understanding, an alphabet in Automata Theory is a finite set of characters or symbols.. @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: @Stoner Yes. Just remember sequences *usually* start at index 0, but I assume the intent of the author referring to 1 just means he views 1 as the first character of the string.

Comment: @Stoner Can you provide a reference to the article/blog/book you're reading?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Its "Genome-Scale Algorithm Design Biological Sequence Analysis in the Era of  High-throughput sequencing" by Alexandru I. Tomescu, Djamal Belazzougui, Fabio Cunial, and Veli Mäkinen. 
http://www.genome-scale.info/

Comment: In particular, I was looking at the definition of the Burrows-Wheeler transform via the suffix array.